# Django queries gets slower over time

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance

I have a django application and a mysql database table having around 30,000 entries. 
I have to process each entry one by one, do some computation and store the result   in database.

When I start processing, the time taken to process 100 entries is around 40 seconds. But this time keeps on growing. So after processing 1000 entries, the time goes to 1 minute, then after processing 2000 entries, the time to compute 100 entries move to 1 minute 30 seconds. 
If I stop the server, and start computing again from say 2000th entry, then the time taken to process 100 entries becomes 40 seconds again, but keeps on increasing as more entries are processed.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Is it in debug mode?

Comment: No, it's not in debug mode.

Comment: Show the code then please.

Comment: Code of insert process and also the models. What versions of Django and Python? What database server?

Answer (score 0):

- Sounds like you need an index.
- Don't process one row at a time; use SQL to process all rows 'simultaneously'.  Describe the processing; we may be able to get more specific.

Comment: Not always so simple. Django hides most of the complexity of SQL statements, and it may not be so easy to rewrite for bulk updates. Django pretty much always has at least one index per table, often many more - all created automagically.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will provide the info. But in this case, the Django models will provide the same info in a more concise format.

Comment: I can read `CREATE TABLE`, and I can see the indexes that were magically generated.  I can't read Django.

Comment: But I can :-) Right now we have to see what user9637850 comes up with.